# android app which has shortcut icons to specific apps inside it

Tags: java, android

-I have created an android app that has 2 buttons to  download apks from internet server if not already installed on the device. 
-I want to provide shortcut icons of these newly installed apps in my application.
I've seen a posts about launcher apps but they list out shortcuts for all apps. I want specifically for my 2 apps. 
Is there a way to do it?

here's the code for existing app.

//MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.appcommunication;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button app1, app2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        app1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        app2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
         final boolean app1Installed = appInstalledOrNot("com.example.cameraphonegap");
         final boolean app2Installed = appInstalledOrNot("com.example.webviewexample");

         if(app1Installed){
             app1.setEnabled(false);
             app1.setText("App1 Installed ");
         }else{
             app1.setEnabled(true);
         }

         if(app2Installed){
             app2.setEnabled(false);
             app2.setText("App2 Installed ");
         }else{
             app2.setEnabled(true);
         }

        app1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                    System.out.println("App is not installed on your phone");
                    Log.d("NOT installed","App not installed on your phone");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App1 Not Installed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                      Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                      Uri.parse("https://www.dropbox.com/s/9vyvypj9qxjanb/CameraPhoneGap.apk"));
                      startActivity(browserIntent);



            }
        });

        app2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    System.out.println("App is not installed on your phone");
                    Log.d("NOT installed","App not installed on your phone");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App2 Not Installed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                      Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                      Uri.parse("https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2z299661ibmhm/webviewExample.apk"));
                      startActivity(browserIntent);



            }
        });
    }

    private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean app_installed = false;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            app_installed = true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            app_installed = false;
        }
        return app_installed;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

//activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:background="#7FFFD4">



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Install app1" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Install app2" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

//Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.appcommunication"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.appcommunication.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented a workaround by saving the ic_launcher of these apps and using it as ImageButtons for launching the apps.      But I need something automatic for the icons when I use the packageName of the apps..

//code for ImageButton:

```
ImageButton launchApp1=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    launchApp1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if(app1Installed){
                        Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager()
                                .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.cameraphonegap");
                        startActivity(LaunchIntent);}else{
                             Log.d("installed","App1 not installed on your phone");
                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                              "App1 Not Installed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }

                }
            });
```

// activity_main.xml

```
  <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/app1" />
```

[image: The launch icon for apps which are installed by my applications]

Answer (score 1):

How about serving these images from the server as well? You can host the images(key values for the package name?) for these apps somewhere and list them inside a listview on your app?

This is the exact thing you want to implement but using a different method to achieve it then what you are trying to do.

Comment: yeah thats exactly what I was saying

Comment: Can't we do something automatic than actually accessing the ic_launcher of the app? by just using the app's PackageName to get the launch shortcut?